# Ajax Submit to asp.net mvc post action or turn collection into json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the Row ID for each table row where Finalize has been checked and post that string/json to an ASP.net MVC Controller. The Ajax is giving me problems. I managed to grab the data that needs to be submitted; but I'm not sure what the best way to proceed is. Do I need to create a json object and then post that or is there a simple way I can post what I have? I tried the json route and didn't get very far so I went back to this, which is at least grabbing the correct data.

```js
            finalize = function() {
              var tableData = "";
              $('#results').find('tr').each(function() {
                var row = $(this);
                if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                  tableData = tableData + $(this).find('td:first').text() + '\n'; // get ID
                }
              });

              //var myRows = JSON.parse(tableData);
              //$.post("/Journal/SaveEntry", { Row: myRows });

              alert(tableData);
            };
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/maxazan/jquery-treegrid/blob/master/js/jquery.treegrid.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/maxazan/jquery-treegrid/blob/master/js/jquery.treegrid.bootstrap3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table tree truncate_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class=" info">
      <th>Row ID</th>
      <th>...</th>
      <th>Finalize</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="treegrid-1">
      <td>
        <span class="treegrid-expander"></span>
        R4915
      </td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Finalize" value="Finalize">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="treegrid-2">
      <td>
        <span class="treegrid-expander"></span>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://example.com" class="vt-p">
                    R4942
                </a>
      </td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Finalize" value="Finalize">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="finalize()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Finalize</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming here that return a collection of the ID's would be more useful that a string which you would then need to split on the controller

Html

```
<button type="button" id="finalize" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Finalize</button>
```

Script

```
$('#finalize').click(function() {
  var idArray = new Array();
  $('#results').find('tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
    if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
      idArray.push(row.find('td:first').text());
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SaveEntry", "Journal")';
    type: 'post'
    traditional: true,
    data: { values: idArray }
  }) 
});
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult SaveEntry(string[] values) // or int[] values if the ID is typeof int
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is most likely [jquery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and post your form. Look at following blog post, [Using jQuery to submit ASP .NET MVC form](http://kitsula.com/Article/Using-jQuery-to-submit-ASP-.NET-MVC-form).

Answer (score 0):

please change your finalize function:

```
    finalize = function() 
    {
          var tableData = "";
          $('#results').find('tr').each(function() {
            var row = $(this);
            if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')) 
            {
              tableData = tableData + row.find('td:first > a').text() + '\n'; 
            }
          });

          //$.post("/Journal/SaveEntry", tableData); // parse json at your controller

          alert(tableData);
        };
```